# Are there taxes for exchanging goods in a barter transaction?

Tags: taxes, currency, business

For example, if I trade someone 10 apples for 10 strawberries, do I or my trading partner need to pay taxes? Do I need to pay taxes if I do business without using officially issued currencies?

If this varies between countries, what are some countries that don't tax this kind of business?

Comment: FYI, Bartering was a potentially really big up and coming industry in the late 70s and early 80s. It was touted as exactly what your question asks. A way to get around taxes. Of course, being successful, the Feds put a quick stop to that with the "Tax & Equity Fiscal Responsibility Act" of 1982. (I only remember this because a group of very wealthy individuals heavily involved in starting up a bartering network would meet at the restaurant I worked in. From time to time they'd even have congresspeople in on their meetings).....

Comment: ....Needless to say, politicians couldn't figure out how their personal pockets would be lined, thus they shut the industry down by passage of TEFRA in 1982.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep in mind that all of the information below assumes:

1. The barter occurs outside a black market and by agents who wish to comply with the law. Black markets are a different issue.
2. You are fully aware that I am not a tax professional, so although I've tried to provide sources where possible, speak to someone who knows the laws of your respective country if this question is anything more than a curiosity.

That being said, here are some examples of national tax laws relating to barter transactions. Obviously this isn't an exhaustive list, but based on my grossly non-representative sample, I think it's fairly safe to assume that barter transactions are more likely taxable than not.

### United States

You're referring to a barter system; in the United States, the IRS is [very specific](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Miscellaneous-Income) about this (see the section titled **Bartering**).

> Bartering is an exchange of property or services. The fair market
> value of goods and services exchanged is fully taxable and must be
> included on Form 1040 in the income of both parties.

The IRS also provides [more details](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc420.html):

> Bartering occurs when you exchange goods or services without
> exchanging money. An example of bartering is a plumber doing repair
> work for a dentist in exchange for dental services. You must include
> in gross income in the year of receipt the fair market value of goods
> and services received in exchange for goods or services you provide or
> may provide under the bartering arrangement.
>
> Generally, you report this income on [Form 1040, Schedule C (PDF)](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sc.pdf),
> Profit or Loss from Business or [Form 1040, Schedule C-EZ (PDF)](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sce.pdf), Net
> Profit from Business. If you failed to report this income, correct
> your return by filing a [Form 1040X (PDF)](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040x.pdf). Refer to [Topic 308](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc308.html) for
> amended return information.

So yes, the net value of bartered goods or services is most likely taxable.

### Australia

According to the [Australian Tax Office](http://www.ato.gov.au/content/downloads/bus35349_n9748.pdf):

> Barter transactions are assessable and deductible for income tax
> purposes to the same extent as other cash or credit transactions.

### United Kingdom

[Her Majesty's Revenue and Customs](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/vat/managing/special-situations/samples.htm#4) states that:

> If you supply services or goods (new or second-hand) and receive other
> goods or services in payment, there are two separate supplies:
>
> - the supply from you to your customer
> - the supply from your customer to you
>
> You must account for VAT, and so must your customer if they're
> VAT-registered. The VAT treatment is the same as for part-exchanges.
> You must both account for VAT on the amounts you would each have paid
> for the goods or services if there had been no barter and they had
> been paid for with money.

### Russia

Searching the website of the [Federal Tax Service](http://nalog.ru/) for the Russian/Cryllic word for barter (`бартер`) doesn't yield any results, but that might be because even between Google Translate and the rest of the internet, I don't speak Russian. That being said, I did manage to find [this](http://www.nalog.ru/fl/fl_ndfl/) ([translated](http://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5.) from the first full paragraph of the Russian, beginning with "Налог на доходы...":

> The tax on personal income is paid by citizens of the Russian
> Federation with all types of income received by them in the calendar
> year, either in cash or in kind.

Since bartering would probably qualify as an [in kind transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_kind), it would likely be taxable.

### South Africa

The South African Revenue Service [includes barter transactions](http://www.sars.gov.za/Tools/Documents/DocumentDownload.asp?FileID=76428) in the supply of goods taxed under the VAT.

> The term “supply” is defined very broadly and includes all forms of
> supply and any derivative of the term, irrespective of where the
> supply is effected. The term includes performance in terms of a sale,
> rental agreement, instalment credit agreement or barter transaction.

Look for section 3.6, **Supply and Taxable Supply**, found on p17 of the current version of the linked document.

Answer (score 4):

Generally it is a taxable transaction. Basic principle of taxation everywhere is that the mean of payment doesn't matter. If the income is taxable - it is taxable regardless of the unit of currency you used. It can be a strawberry, a bitcoin, a gold nugget, or a dollar, it doesn't change a thing about how it is taxed.

If you look at the [United States tax code definition of taxable income](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/62), for example, you will find **no** mention whatsoever of any currency. Similarly with other tax laws I'm familiar with. I'm sure there's no such limitation in Australia.